# Density in $\text{L}^p$: a technical question

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

***Notation***: $C_0$ is the space of continuous functions with compact support.

**Definition.** A sequence $\{\rho_m\}\subseteq C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is said regularizing sequece if for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$:

$1.\;\rho_m\ge 0\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{R}^n;$

$2.\;\rho_m=0\;\text{if}\;|x|\ge\frac{1}{m};$

$3.\;\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho_m(x)\;dx=1$

> **Theorem.** Let $\{\rho_m\}\subseteq C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a regularizing sequence.

> $1.\;$ Let $f\in\text{L}^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$; then $\{\rho_m\star f\}\subseteq C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

> $2.\;$ Let $f\in\text{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n), p\in[1,\infty).$
> Then $\{\rho_m\star f\}\subseteq\text{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

**$\color{red}{Note}.$** Let $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and suppose I have shown the following
$$\color{blue}{|(\rho_m\star g)(x)-g(x)|=\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho_m(x-y)[g(y)-g(x)]\;dy\bigg |\le \sup_{|x-y|<\frac{1}{m}}|g(y)-g(x)|\;\text{for all}\;x\in\mathbb{R}^n}$$

**Theorem.** Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set; let $p\in [1,\infty)$. Then $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $\text{L}^p(\Omega).$

**Proof.** Let $f\in\text{L}^p(\Omega)$ fixed. We know that for all $\varepsilon >0$ exists $g\in C_0(\Omega)$ such that $\lVert f-g \rVert_p< \varepsilon$.

Let $\{\rho_m\}$ a regularizing sequence;

***Question***: $\color{red}{\text{why is the following statement true?}}$

since $g$ have compact support, $\color{blue}{\text{the inequality in blue}}$ implies that

$$\color{red}{\text{supp}(\rho_m\star g)\subseteq\Omega\quad\text{for all}\quad m>\frac{1}{d(\text{supp}(g),\partial\Omega)}}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if we pick $x\in \Omega^c \subseteq supp(g)^c$, then $g(x)=0$. This is because we extend $g$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by setting it to zero outside of $\Omega$ as hal4math remarked in the comment below. For the $m$ as above, we also have
$$\vert x-y\vert < \frac{1}{m} <d(supp(g), \partial \Omega).$$

Assume now that $g(y)\neq 0$, then $y\in supp(g)\subseteq \Omega$. However, then there exists some $z\in [x, y]$ such that $z\in \partial \Omega$ and thus
$$\vert y-z\vert \leq \vert x-y\vert <d(supp(g), \partial \Omega).$$
This is a contradiction as $z\in \partial \Omega$ and $y\in supp(g)$. Thus, we get that $g(y)=0$ and hence the RHS of the blue inequality vanishes. Hence, the LHS of the blue inequality vanishes as well and so we are not in the support of the convolution.

In a nutshell, to get out of $\Omega$ on a straight line, you have to pass through its boundary and then we note that we are "by assumption" too far away to be in the support of $g$.

Comment: I think as a technical detailed you as well as the proof is using the fact that you can extend every $g\in C_0(\Omega)$ to a function in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by extending it by zero in the complement of its support. (I know this is nothing fancy, I just thought maybe it might be worth mentioning).

Comment: @hal4math You are absolutely correct. I did not mention this point as otherwise as the convolution would not even be defined if $g$ was not extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$ (I thought/guessed/hoped that this was clear for the OP). But you might be right that this could be a key point that was unclear.